# Spark Decision tree fit runs in 1 task

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, emr

I am trying to "train" a `DecisionTreeClassifier` using Apache Spark running in a cluster in [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce). Even though I can see that there are around 50 Executors added and that the features are created by querying a Postgres database using SparkSQL and stored in a DataFrame.
The DesisionTree `fit` method takes for many hours even though the Dataset is not that big (10.000 db entries with a couple of hundreds of bytes each row).
I can see that there is only one task for this so I assume this is the reason that it's been so slow.
Where should I look for the reason that this is running in one task?
Is it the way that I retrieve the data?
I am sorry if this is a bit vague but I don't know if the code that retrieves the data is relevant, or is it a parameter in the algorithm (although I didn't find anything online), or is it just Spark tuning?
I would appreciate any direction!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask about your cluster configuration ? How do you submit your applications ? What type of instances do you use ? etc.

Comment: Yes...I create a fat jar using `sbt assembly` (it's a scala project) and run it using `spark-submit `. I run it in yarn-cluster mode, using 10 core instances of r3.2xlarge size, executor-memory 15G, driver-memory 40G, 2 cores per executor and `num-executors 1600` (maybe this is not very good, but I thing it gets overriden by the max number of executors),

Comment: There is one issue with YARN on EMR. It launches 1 executor per node. I didn't investigate that yet to be honest. But that's what the AWS EMR support team told me when I've contacted them. I think that it can be actually a lead. It seems better to launch 20 r3.xlarge than 10 r3.2x and so on... You might also need to plug on ganglia to have a better understand on what's happening with your cluster.

Comment: I plugged in Ganglia, it's very helpful, thank you! Concerning the executors with the aforementioned config there are 27 executors created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark relies on data locality. It seems that all the data is located in a single place. Hence spark uses a single partition to process it. You could apply a repartition or state the number of partitions you would like to use at load time. I would also look into the decision tree Api and see if you can set the number of partitions for it specifically. 
Basically, partitions are your level of parallelism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From my investigation I think this is the most probable cause too...I am checking now to verify!

Comment: I run some more tests...the good thing is that I can see now that the job runs in multiple tasks. However it is still pretty slow as the execution gets stuck in the last task of the decision tree fit...any ideas how I can understand the bottleneck? I installed also Ganglia and the specific core doesn't seem to throttle at all :/ In any case I will accept your answer, thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Is it stuck or slow? Can you share some numbers of data size, partitions, time?

Comment: Yes sure...It is really slow. I have tried from 27 to 100 partitions (running in 27 executors). All the tasks finish in a few minutes (max 7) or even seconds, but the last task of `DecisionTreeClassifier.fit` (specifically `take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:110`) takes 1.2 hours. The data size is of KB size :/